# Windows batch file variables containing whitespace/special chars inside a loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic, netsh

Using this in a batch file on Windows 10:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "profile=NetworkProfileName"
set result=

for /F "tokens=2 delims=: usebackq" %%F IN (`netsh wlan show profile %profile% key^=clear ^| findstr "Key Content"`) do (
  set "result=%%F"
)

echo %profile% has password:!result!
endlocal
```

I get the **expected** results:

```
NetworkProfileName has password: SuperSecretPassword
```

When I use a network profile name **containing special characters and whitespace** like this

```
set "profile=Wu-Tang LAN"
```

The profile is not found in the loop, and the password variable remains blank:

```
Wu-Tang LAN has password:
```

If I run this command directly in `cmd`:

```
netsh wlan show profile "Wu-Tang LAN" key=clear | findstr "Key Content"
```

I get the expected output:

```
Key Content : OtherSecretPassword
```

Even ChatGPT 4 couldn't get me over the line! What is the secret?

Comment: you did something different in the command line: you quoted the profile (because it contains spaces). You didn't quote them in the script. Use `"%profile%"` instead of `%profile%`

Comment: Yeah you have to do it on the command line if you have spaces, right? Adding the quotes into the bat file around the variable results in no matches in either case (both with and without whitespace or special characters)

Comment: I can't see why you are using `usebackq`. I'd remove that and fix the quotes. Personally, I put `delims` last in the options. With your syntax, how is `for` supposed to know whether the space is part of the `delims` string or an option-separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had made any attempt to read the built-in documentation for `net.exe`, you'd have seen that the suggested syntax should have been `wlan show profiles name="%profile%" key=clear`, which not only clearly shows your profile name doublequoted, it also uses `profiles` not `profile`. If you next took a look at the built-in documentation for `findstr.exe`, you'd have noted that as you are wanting to match a space character, you should be using `/C:"Key Content"`, to match those together.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "Profile=NetworkProfileName"

Set "Key="
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe WLAN Show
 Profiles Name^="%Profile%" Key^=Clear ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R
 /C:"Key Content" 2^>NUL') Do Set "Key=%%H"
If Not Defined Key GoTo :EOF
Set "Key=%Key:~1%"

Echo %Profile% has password:%Key%
Pause
```

The idea above was designed not to use a space character as a delimiter just in case there is a possibility that the 'password' begins with a leading space character itself. You should also note that I have not enabled delayed expansion, which would cause issues if your 'password' included exclamation marks. It should be noted however, that should the password contain percent characters, you would need to perform extra work if you wanted to expand `%Key%` with `Echo`.